# Daemon not reactiing

Tags: c, pipe, client-server, daemon

I've already asked a similar question a few days ago. Basically I have to make a daemon-client communicate via named tubes. The client part is done and sends messages correctly, but the daemon part seems to not be receiving anything... Here's the code:

```
void makeDaemon(){
  int i,fd0,fd1,fd2;
  pid_t pid;
  struct sigaction sa;
  struct rlimit rl;

  umask(0);

  if(getrlimit(RLIMIT_NOFILE, &rl)<0) exit(EXIT_FAILURE); 

  if((pid=fork())<0) exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  if(pid>0) exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);

  setsid();

  sa.sa_handler=SIG_IGN;
  sigemptyset(&sa.sa_mask);
  sa.sa_flags=0;

  if(sigaction(SIGHUP, &sa, NULL)<0) exit(EXIT_FAILURE);

  if((pid=fork())<0) exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  if(pid>0) exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);

  //if(chdir("/")<0) exit(EXIT_FAILURE);

  if(rl.rlim_max=RLIM_INFINITY) rl.rlim_max=1024;
  for(i=0;i< rl.rlim_max; i++) close(i);

  close(STDIN_FILENO);
  close(STDOUT_FILENO);
  close(STDERR_FILENO);

  //sigaction(SIGUSR1,&sac,NULL);
}

int main(){
  makeDaemon();

  char* path="./run/pipes/saturnd-request-pipe";
  char* path2="./run/pipes/saturnd-reply-pipe";

  //Creation d'un pipe au cas où il n'existe pas
  //mkfireply_pipe(path,0666);
  int timeout=5000;
  struct pollfd pf[1];
    
  int request_pipe;
  

  while(1){
    request_pipe=open(path,O_RDONLY);
    if(request_pipe==-1){
        perror("Erreur d'ouverture du pipe");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    pf[0].fd=request_pipe;
    pf[0].events=POLLIN;

    int p=poll(pf,1,timeout);
      
    if(pf[0].revents & POLLIN){
      char tmp1[2];
      ssize_t s=read(request_pipe,tmp1,2);
       if(s==-1) exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
       printf("%s\n",tmp1);
       int i=1;
    }else{
      printf("Timed out\n");
      break;
    }
    return 0;
  }
}
```

My question is, should I maybe make a handler containing this while loop so that the daemon can receive a signal? As of right now, it just times out and dies. We cannot use sockets, and everything is done via these two names pipes. Any suggestion would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Why do you need a timeout? Are you sure the client is sending something before the timeout?

Comment: Note that `read()` doesn't add a null terminator. `%s` format requires a null-terminated string.

Comment: Someone made the same comment about `%s` in your previous question.

Comment: I used the poll function to ensure something is getting written in the pipe. In theory yes, the client sends a request (and I know it works because it passed all the simulated tests)

Comment: It just doesnt seem to know how and where to look in the request pipe to correctly read an instruction.

Comment: You don't even need a client. Just type `echo x > run/pipes/saturnd-request-pipe` in the shell.

Comment: Typo: `if(rl.rlim_max=RLIM_INFINITY)` should use `==`.

Comment: You're closing stdout. How do you expect to see the output of printf?

Comment: BTW, there's no need to close stdin, stdout, and stderr explicitly, since they'll be closed in the `for` loop.

Comment: Hello, thanks for the answers, I really appreciate... sadly we have to use the client to communicate with the daemon since it's our final project, that's why I'm having problems with making them communicate via pipes.

Comment: You need both for the project, but you can test them separately.

Comment: You cannot write onto stdout (so `printf()` doesn't work after `makeDaemon()` is executed) because you have `close(STDOUT_FILENO)`d the three redirectable file descriptors)  And you have done it twice (once in the loop, and later specifically in the last part of `makeDaemon()`.